# C# .NET choice of Multithreading approach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I've looked over multiple similar questions on SO, but I still couldn't answer my own question.

I have a console app (an Azure Webjob actually) which does file processing and DB management. Some heavy data being downloaded from multiple sources and processed on the DB.

Here's an example of my code:

```
var dbLongIndpendentProcess = doProcesAsync();

var myfilesTasks  = files.Select(file => Task.Run(
                async () =>
{
// files processing 
}

await myfilesTasks.WhenAll();
await dbLongIndpendentProcess;
// continue with other stuff;
```

It all works fine and does what I am expecting it to do. There are other tasks running in this whole process, but I guess the idea is clear from the code above.

**My question:** Is this a fair way of approaching this, or would I get more performance (or sense?) by doing the good old "manual" multithreading? The main reason I chose this approach was that it's simple and straightforward.

However, wasn't async/await primarily aimed at doing asynchronous not to block the main (UI) thread. Here I don't have any UI and I am not doing anything. event-driven.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to `await` the calls immediately, you can fire a task, assign it to a variable, then perform some additional work and await the task later when the value is needed. In a kitchen for example you would boil rice, but you wouldn't wait for that pot to boil, instead you'd complete other jobs and later check on the pot. In terms of the 'manual' multithreading, creating threads can be expensive, especially if you don't know what you're doing, personally I'd say it's down to your preference and particularly the complexity of the job.

Comment: it's worthwhile to add that you should correctly implement the cancellation pattern, since you explicitly deal with long tasks.

Comment: Yes, long running tasks should have a `CancellationToken` so you can gracefully cleanup and free resources, instead of simply tearing a `Thread` or `Task` down which could possibly result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: @ColinM please help me understand. "You don't need to await the calls immediately, you can fire a task, assign it to a variable, then perform some additional work and await the task later when the value is needed." Was that a general comment or in reference to my code for it seems to me that I am doing exactly that. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In general as a pointer since a lot of people tend to introduce the `async` and `await` keywords for the sake of it while expecting a performance boost when really it's to perform an operation **asynchronously**. Looking at your code, you're doing it just fine by spinning off an operation and assigning it to `dbLongIndependentProcess` and then `await`ing that task later.

Comment: I would also note that multithreading doesn't guarantee better performance.  If network I/O is your bottleneck, then multithreading won't help since you can't download multiple files faster by requesting them all at the same time.

Comment: @DStanley agreed. But it's not only downloading but processing as well. Basically for files a b c of different size, b can finish downloading as start being processed while a, c are still in the pipeline and will hit the processing as soon as they're done downloading - all independent of each other.

Comment: @agfc True - it would allow you to stagger tasks.

Comment: It was, the primary motivation was WinRT.  A pretty unfriendly api primarily designed for mobile devices, almost everything requires async code.  A console mode app is fundamentally different from a GUI app, console I/O is thread-safe.  So it does not have a synchronization provider like a GUI app always needs.  And your await continuations always run on a thread-pool thread.  Something you still need to be aware of, the console is thread-safe but the user's eyes are not and cannot parse intermingled output from multiple threads.

Comment: Most likely none of this has a meaningful impact on throughput. Do what's most convenient to you. Often, async IO is inconvenient. For example, you can't pause the debugger to see what the app is doing since no thread currently does anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're multithreading by using this approach (except the single Task.Run), async doesn't generally run things on separate threads, it only prevents things from blocking. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt674882.aspx#Anchor_5

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
>   synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
>   method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a
>   background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process
>   that's just waiting for results to become available.

It would be much better to use tasks for the things you want to multithread, then you can take better advantage of machine cores and resources. You might want to look at a task based solution such as Pipelining (which may work in this scenario) etc...: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff963548.aspx or another alternative.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in my code dbLongIndpendentProcess will run on the main thread still but will not block the flow because nothing is actually happening there, however my myfilesTasks collection will run in parallel. (Well, I know they do...:) )

Comment: @agfc The DB operation isn't happening on the main thread.  It's not using any thread at all to do its work.  The work doesn't require time on your CPU to make progress.

Comment: @Servy clearly the DB operation does not, but the question was : "is the c# task called dbLongIndpendentProcess created on the same thread or not"?  It seems that indeed it is on the same thread and thanks to the async it's not blocking the execution of the calling method. Am I correct?

Comment: @agfc You *start* the asynchronous operation from the main thread, yes.  It has nothing to do with it beyond that.

Comment: @Servy can you clarify that please. Say dbLongIndpendentProcess  had nothing to do with the DB, but were rather a CPU job. How would it impact the flow of my code?

Comment: @agfc If it were a synchronous CPU bound operation then it'd block until it finishes, and your code wouldn't be doing work in parallel.  When you want to run synchronous CPU bound operations asynchronously in a thread pool thread you can use `Task.Run` to create a task that represents that work being done by a thread pool.

Comment: @agfc with async there is no thread really it just makes sure things don't block other operations. Which is absolutely fine if your DB step doesn't do anything but get blocked by the db operation. However, it gets murkier when it has something more computationally expensive in it. I personally hate mixing the async and tasks as I think it makes exception handling more difficult.

Comment: Also @agfc you might want to take that async off the function inside that Task.Run as that does get a little strange in my experience.

Comment: @grrrrrrrrrrrrr That's an interesting thought. What do you think is going on there and how would the code behave differently with and without that async ?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I think it will run it as though it's async from inside the thread, and I'm not sure of the side effects of that.. I guess it's there so you can use async await inside the function, but in reality you don't really need it as you're in a new thread anyway and only the function you are in will be blocked. I'd remove it incase it does something fruity like bypassing the exception handling of the task etc...